# Building and deploying cordova app in Visual Studio for Windows 10 Mobile - debugger spits javascript runtime errors

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, windows-10-mobile

When I'm building javascript app for Cordova Windows 10 Mobile and debugging with Visual studio 2015 (but before, running module bundling from webpack config, i.e. `webpack --bail --progress --profile` using Task Runner Explorer addon), app most of the time builds and deploys, so I can run it and see the loading screen (css animation before appears login form to app), but while debugging I get JavaScript runtime errors, like:

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/3.0)'. 
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'ms-appx-web://com.pg.apptracking1617vendor341/www/vendor/app.31001d2eb956c2104cb7.js'. 
Exception was thrown at line 1861, column 3 in eval code
0x800a1389 - JavaScript runtime error: Number.prototype.toPrecision: 'this' is not a Number object
Exception was thrown at line 2397, column 5 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.endsWith: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2401, column 7 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.endsWith: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2397, column 5 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.includes: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2401, column 7 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.includes: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2397, column 5 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.startsWith: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2401, column 7 in eval code
0x800a1608 - JavaScript runtime error: String.prototype.startsWith: first argument cannot be a RegExp
Exception was thrown at line 2603, column 3 in eval code
0x800a1389 - JavaScript runtime error: Number expected
Exception was thrown at line 2735, column 33 in eval code
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: 2
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 48 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
Exception was thrown at line 2836, column 3 in eval code
0x800a1396 - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.sort: argument is not a JavaScript object
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 48 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.sort: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.forEach: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.map: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.filter: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.some: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.every: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.reduce: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 11 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.reduceRight: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 48 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.indexOf: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 2788, column 48 in eval code
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.lastIndexOf: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 3283, column 39 in eval code
0x800a1398 - JavaScript runtime error: RegExp.prototype.toString: 'this' is not a RegExp object
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 5114, column 7 in eval code
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
```

While in Android version of Cordova compiled app, those error are probably absent, because app starts and login form loads normally - I can login to account, edit options .etc, so app is overall usable.

Note that it's Cordova app for Windows 10 Mobile, so thanks to "remote mode" no additional "safe scripting" are needed, AFAIK.

Anybody experienced sane/similar problems with building Cordova apps for Windows 10 Mobile?

Thanks for eventual help.

Comment: Hey @Leo-MSFT, could You point me, where should I precisely look for problem?